# Optimization of deletion nodes in 2-d array

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have double dimensional array of dimensions 720x90. Let's denote rows by R and C as columns.
R1 = {C1,...,C90}

....

R720 = {C1,...C90}

Now, I want to see if any of the data in any of the rows appears anywhere else in any other rows. For instance, lets say the data in row 470 and column 67 is a duplicate of row 672 and column 34. In that case, I want to remove both row 470 and row 672 from the data set and continue checking. After I have checked all the rows, I want to print just the index of the rows that have survived. I have written a brute-force method of this. However, when I run this code, it never returns and I am not able to diagnose why. Also, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
//check all the subsets of the interleaved data
public static int checkSubsets(String[][] subsets){
    List subset = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i< 720; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 90; j++)
            subset.add(subsets[i][j]);
    }
    Object duplicate; 
    Iterator itr = subset.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){    
        duplicate = itr.next();    
        while(itr.hasNext()){    
            subset.remove(duplicate);
            itr=subset.iterator(); //to avoid concurrent modification
            itr.next();    
        }
    }
    return subset.size();
}
```

Clarifications: Lets say I am iterating through looking at each value in the matrix. I take the first value in R1 C1 (row 1 - column 1). I find that these values are found somewhere in the 12, 346,123, 356 row. Then I remove all those rows from the matrix. So now the  matrix is 5 rows smaller. I stop checking row 1 now and move onto row 2. I continue checking, skipping over row 12, 346, 123, and 356. Hence, I am after a row that is unique (has 90 values that are all unique).

Comment: You are using mis-using iterators (your inner while loop is infinite), and even if you used them correctly, I don't see any connection between the logic you described in words and the logic you implemented.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to solve.  In case for row 10 col 1 is duplicated with a number in row 11 , and row 10 col2 is duplicated with another number in row 12, do you want only row 10 and 11 removed from checking and overlooks the duplication of row 10 and 12?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer on that. I want all rows to be removed. So, yes. Including row 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is almost there, but helpfull data-structures are missing.

To add a bit of spice I used Java 8 somewhat.

As you did one can collect the values to check for duplicates.
However one needs to remember the first row of that value, as only there it is still unknown whether a duplicate exists.

```
public static int checkSubsets(String[][] subsets) {

    // The results.
    final Set<Integer> duplicateRows = new HashSet<>();

    // From the first occurrence of a duplicate value we do not know it yet,
    // so need to remember.
    final Map<String, Integer> firstRowOfValue = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < subsets.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < subsets[i].length; ++j) {
            final String value = subsets[i][j];
            Integer oldRow = firstRowOfValue.putIfAbsent(value, i);
            if (oldRow != null) { // Duplicates
                duplicateRows.add(i);
                duplicateRows.add(oldRow);
                // oldRow might already be added if third duplicate or same row.
            }
        }
    }

    IntStream.rangeOf(0, subsets.length)
        .filter(i -> !duplicateRows.contains(i))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    return subsets.length - duplicateRows.size();
}
```

---

The `IntStream` part would be in java 7:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subsets.length; ++i) {
    if (!duplicateRows.contains(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

With java 7 you can safely substitute here `putIfAbsent` with `put`.

Comment: Hello, I am having a little trouble understanding the bottom half. It seems like a mix of c++ and java? Can you please elaborate on that? Also, what I understand so far is that we are saving where we first see a value, and then adding that row and every row thereafter that has the same value into duplicate rows, right?

Comment: The reason I am reassigning the iterator each time is because I want to not do as many calculations as the upper bound. By that I mean, lets say the first value in the first row is found in the 8, 10, 123, 135 row. Then, I no longer want to check any of the values in any of these rows. The reason being is that, I have to call this function 720 times. So if I were to check the upper bound number of times, then that would be 720*720*90. And for my purposes, I can simply eliminate a row if any of the values are repeated. My goal is to find a row that has all 90 values being unique.

Comment: The bottom (IntStream) is java 8. I'll add. Suppose you have `[[2, 3], [2.4], [3, 5]]` then nothing rests, and you have to add both 2 and 3. As far as I understand.

Comment: However if your only concern is to have rows that have no duplicates, like [2, 4] and [3, 5] remaining, I would need to think seriously.

Comment: Right, so in `[[2, 3], [2.4], [3, 5]]` I notice that '2' is in the 2 row. So I remove that row. And I see that '3' is in row 3. So I remove row 3 as well. And since row 1 had at least 1 element that was repeated elsewhere as well, I am removing the first row also. So I am left with no rows that have all unique elements. Is this the same notion you are conveying? Please forgive me, if I misunderstood terribly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the code you wrote has to do with the requirement, I will give you the approach of the answer yet you have to try it yourself first.

it is clear that you need to iterate on each row to check for possible duplicates yet this will cause a performance failure , you can overcome this with a smiple use of HashMap, first store each entry in the map , the key will be the value of the node of the array, and the value should be the coordinates of this node.

When iterating over the array for each row you should find the y coordinates from the map which is common between all nodes of the row, so duplicate rows detected.

In order to avoid keep checking the already removed rows try to store all the rows to be deleted and remove them once you are done, you can use Set to store them to avoid duplicate.

Good luck with the implemenation.